# Android Studio layout management problems

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm new to android studio... So I've been trying to make a simple app. When I want to put two linear layouts in another one, One of them goes out of the frame!
I don't know if I'm doing this right or not.
Also here are the pictures (the second one is the problem):

1)https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3GIQ.jpg

2)https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEN6F.jpg

thanks

Comment: You've probably got 'match_parent' in the attributes if the child linear layouts. Try setting : layout_weight="1" and layout_width="0" for each of the child linear layouts.

Comment: can you post the layout file here so that we can help you out...

Comment: in the image posted, in the right hand pane 'component tree', you have a horizontal layout as parent of a horizontal layout and vertical layout, so what you are getting is the correct output, if you post how your layout should look like, i can definitely help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your pictures, your parent linear layout which contains the other two linear layouts has its orientation set to "horizontal". It must be set to "vertical" to be above each other...

In your parent linear layout, you will find this:

> android:orientation="horizontal"

Change it to:

> android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: @ArmanSh Please don't forget to vote my answer up and mark it as correct... You're welcome! :)

Comment: @ArmanSh Please don't forget to vote my answer up as well... :)

Comment: I need 15 reputations.

Comment: @ArmanSh Alright, no problem, but try to vote it up once you reach 15 reputations. This really means a lot to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal orientation, you need to set both of the inner `LinearLayout` widths to `0dp` and set their weights to `1`.

For veritcal orientation, you need to set both of the inner `LinearLayout` heights to `0dp` and set their weights to `1`.

Without the weight attribute, since the first `LinearLayout` width is set to  `match_parent`, it takes up the entire `LinearLayout`.

### Example:

in your case of a horizontal layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0d"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0d"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```